# windows batch variable's size max

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, size, max

I have a problem with my batch.
the batch test the size of a directory and when it is too big it delete oldest file.

the batch :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
net use T: /d
net use T: \\10.230.78.22\survcam

set dossiure=T:\
set "$max=204010946560"

Echo traitement en cours....

:loop
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('dir %dossiure% ^| find /i "octets"') do (
  set $NbBytes=%%a
  goto:test
)
:test

If %$NbBytes% GTR %$max% (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir %dossiure% /b/a-d/od') do (
       set LeVieux="%dossiure%%%a"
       Echo Destruction de : [!LeVieux!]
       del "!LeVieux!"
       goto:wait
   )
)
goto:fin
:wait
rem ping localhost -n 1
goto:loop
:fin
net use T: /d
echo fini
```

When $max = 85899345920
it is ok (80GiB)
but when $max = 204010946560
it erease many more than the indicated size (190GiB)
it is like it understand 19Gib limit
someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum for a numeric variable in batch is 2^31.

Try calculating in Mib or use 2 variables (Mb and bytes)

---

But, since your variables are both single strings which you know to be numeric, then try

```
set "$$max=000000000000000000000%$max%"
set "$$NbBytes=000000000000000000%$NbBytes%"
if %$$NbBytes:~-18% GTR %$$max:~-18% (
```

That is, prefix the variable with a large number of `0`s then compare the last *n* (I chose 18) characters of the resultant string.

Comment: 2^31 = 2147483648
with that the limit 2GiB
why it work with a limit 80 GiB

Comment: Since the **strings** you are using exceed 2^31, batch will switch to **string-comparison** mode and compare characters left-to-right. All batch variables are strings - `set /a` converts from string to numeric, calculates and then converts back to a string.  Equally, `if` with comparison-operators other than `==` converts from string to numeric then performs the comparison. If either side cannot be converted to a numeric within range, then the comparison will be performed on the raw string.